# How to style textfield recently results

Tags: javascript, html, css

When entering a text in `texfiled` more times, browser offered this text on box below, as on picture. How to style this in `css`? What is this, `JS` or not?
On `Opera browser` box for this results is black on `firefox` is white...

What is the name for this and is there any JS which I can use for that and style manually?

[image]

Comment: @JamieTaylor He's not trying to style a select or option, just the auto complete.

Comment: this is a god question

Comment: Good lord, I didn't realise god would ever have a question. He is omnipotent after all :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a bogstandard `autofill` box that all browsers will offer up. **No you cannot style this**

If you want to style this you'll need to first turn off autofill:

```
 autocomplete="off"
```

Then set up some auto complete box that will require a fair ammount of setting up and giving it data to auto completele with, http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ to name but just one.

Good luck!

Comment: Works with jqueryui.
Thanks!